# Forbidden + sign out using sidekiq/devise/activeadmin on production server with nginx/haproxy/thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, sidekiq

We using sidekiq gem on production server with nginx, haproxy, thin. Also we using sidekiq UI for authenticated admin users (activeadmin):

```
authenticate :admin_user do
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
end
```

After authentication we try to open /sidekiq. Instead of seeing sidekiq ui we receive only "forbidden". Furthermore, we lost devise session. So if we try to open /admin, activeadmin require authentication again.

We facing this issue only on production server, on dev it works fine.

We using: 
nginx(https)
haproxy(http)
thin (http)
sidekiq 4.1.1
devise 3.5.6
activeadmin 1.0.0.pre2
sinatra 1.4.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have proper headers forwarded to your application else rack-protection will block requests.

In Nginx server configuration you need:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

Then in HAProxy you need to forward IP to you app

```
option forwardfor header X-Client
```

I use to have `option forwardfor header X-Real-IP` to transfer IP in app but this is not working for rack-protection.

Comment: Thanks. It helped!